# What is wrong with this proof of inclusion exclusion principle?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion, combinatorial-proofs

I am following the correct proof is given by [Marton](https://people.maths.bris.ac.uk/%7Emb13434/incl_excl_n.pdf). But why is the following **incorrect** ?

F and (E-F) are mutually disjoint and union is $E\cup F$

Therefore Eq1 is $(E\cup F)-(E-F)=F$

(F - E ) and $(E\cap F)$ are independent and Eq2 is

$F- (E\cap F) = F - E$

Eq1 - Eq2 is

$(E\cup F) + (E\cap F) = 2E$

Comment: Presumably you mean that $F - E$ and $E \cap F$ are disjoint rather than independent.

Comment: What does 2E mean? You can't just treat set subtraction as the opposite of set "addition", whatever that would be.

Answer (score 2):

Eq$1$ and Eq$2$ are true but you cannot add or substract "set equations". Kind of why I prefer $E \setminus F$ to $E - F$. Instead you need to think about why set equalities are true, for example by checking both inclusions.
In general, set "addition" is not defined, since the more natural "addition" on sets is the union.

When the sets are taken over spaces on which addition or multiplication or [insert operation] (e.g. groups, rings, vector spaces, etc...) you can start to define sets like $A + B := \{a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$, $\lambda A := \{\lambda a \mid a \in A\}$, $AB := \{ab \mid a \in A, b \in B\}$ and so forth (for convenience) but they will not obey any particular algebraic operation in the way that you'd expect your numbers, elements, vectors, etc... to obey: you can have $A + A = A$, $-A = A = 3A$, $AB = A$, $A + (- A) \neq \emptyset$, and so on.
And that's fine, because that is not what is asked of sets. But that does mean one needs to be more careful when dealing with such notations.

EDIT: Once you go and use a measure like in the link you gave, your equations will make more sense:
Let $\mathbb{P}$ be a probability measure on a measurable space $(\Omega, \mathcal{A})$, and let $(E,F) \in \mathcal{A}^2$.
Then we have, thanks to $\mathbb{P}(A \setminus B) = \mathbb{P}(A) - \mathbb{P}(A \cap B)$ :
$$\begin{split}\mathbb{P}(F) &= \mathbb{P}((E \cup F) \setminus (E \setminus F))\\ &= \mathbb{P}(E \cup F) - \mathbb{P}(E \setminus F)\\ &= \mathbb{P}(E \cup F) - (\mathbb{P}(E) - \mathbb{P}(E \cap F))\end{split}$$
And thus:
$$\mathbb{P}(E \cup F) = \mathbb{P}(E) + \mathbb{P}(F) - \mathbb{P}(E \cap F)$$
So you can prove what Marton showed with set substractions rather than disjoint unions if you want to. However the advantage of Marton's approach is that their method does generalise to measures that can take $+\infty$ as a possible value like the counting measure I mentioned in the comments below, because it only deals with adding positive possibly infinite numbers, while this approach requires the measure to only take finite values.

Also I slightly misjudged your equations, you would have needed to turn one of $E \setminus F$ or $F \setminus E$ to the other one, so that they simplify each other once substracting the equations (once the equations are rewritten with measures that is, not right now).

Comment: 1. I get "operations" on set is not like numbers. But thats exactly what is done in the link by Marton. He just happened to pick another way and proved the principle ?  2. Why is it a principle and not a theorem ?

Comment: @NewStudent What Marton did is do operations with a probability measure, and so they use properties of the function $\mathbf{P}$ to their advantage. But if you were looking for a proof of the principle for finite sets, with cardinals rather than probabilities, the method is pretty much the same (which is because the function which maps a set to its cardinal is also a measure, the counting measure of the collection of sets you're working with). As for why it's a principle and not a theorem or a lemma, erm, I do not know frankly.

Comment: you are wise :-) My Eq1 is "symmetrical" to Marton's Eq1 (i.e. F and E are reversed). Is that why I did not get the proof ?

Comment: @NewStudent Your equations will still get the job done (as in Eq$1$ $-$ Eq$2$ will still give the solution after simplifications) but only if you look at the probabilities of the sets and not just the sets themselves. So in order to get the proof you need to understand what $\mathbf{P}$ is and does.

Comment: I got P and cardinality are "measures" from your previous comment. But how will *my* eqns prove the principle ? Marton's and mine are different as shown in  my previous comment

Comment: @NewStudent Edited my answer.

Comment: thanks for the edit. I guess choosing eqs which prove the principle is **luck of the draw** . You had to modify my **Eq2** to prove the principle. I guess I will rest it saying **my** eqns wont prove the principle. 

Are you part of any discord channel or SE chatgroup since I am getting warning of extended discussion here